# Input type file não funciona na webview

Tags: java, android, file-upload, webview, android-webview

Tenho uma pagina em HTML que tem um *form* de *upload* de imagens
no Chrome no pc ou em qualquer navegador funciona
mas no meu aplicativo que tem uma `WebView` que abre esta página
ai clicar em *choose* *file* ele não faz nada.

É possível arrumar isso para escolher um arquivo ou abrir a câmera do aparelho ?

( só escolher o arquivo já resolve )

Segue o código do meu fragmento:

```
public class F_Adm extends Fragment implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

    private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_adm, container, false);

        mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setListener(getActivity(), this);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://desapegogames.com.br/area-administrativa");

        return rootView;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mWebView.onResume();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mWebView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mWebView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        mWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(String url) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/offline.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) {
    }
}
```

Comment: você quer que seu site tenho a possibilidade de abrir um método no seu código de android?

Comment: não. Quero apenas fazer upload de arquivos pelo input tyle='file' que tem em uma pagina html so que pela minha webview nao funciona mas pelo chrome do celular sim.

Comment: Esta ativado o javascritp do webview?

Comment: sim ta ativo. ele ate abre para selecionar o arquivo mas quando seleciona ele não preenche o input

Comment: tentei mudar para esse plugin https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView tbm da a mesma coisa vc escolhe o arquivo e o campo não é preenchido.

Comment: Faz um bom tempo que fiz um **webview** mas me lembro que tive um caso semelhante e precisei importar o motor **webkit**, com isso meu webview rodava como se fosse o **chrome**. Não sei se é a sua solução, mas qualquer coisa vc me diz.

Comment: Já viu as respostas a esta [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5907369/2556111) no SOen?

Comment: tentei tbm usar i webkit do chrome e não rolou vou postar meu cod aqui.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vou te auxiliar de acordo com a [documentação do **WebView**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Segue imagem esquema do componente visual `WebView`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Definindo variáveis:

```
private static final String TAG = TestActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private WebView meuWebView;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String diretorioFotoImagem;
```

Definindo um método para armazenar imagem temporariamente `armazenarImagemTemp()`:

```
 private File armazenarImagemTemp() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}
```

Definindo um método para adaptar as configurações padrões do `WebView` com o nome `setWebview`:

```
 private void setWebview(WebView webView) {
    WebSettings set = webView.getSettings();

    // habilita javascript
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // oculta zoom no sdk HONEYCOMB+
        set.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }

    // habilita debugging remoto via chrome {inspect}
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
    meuWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Só pode haver um método `onActivityResult()` em cada Activity. Esse método é chamado na sequência de cada chamada a `startActivityForResult`.
Ao chamar o método `startActivityForResult` é passado, no segundo parâmetro, um `requestCode`. Veja:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }

    Uri[] results = null;

    // verifica se a resposta esta ok com a variável estática {RESULT_OK} do Activity
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(data == null) {
            // se não houver dados solicitará que tire uma foto
            if(diretorioFotoImagem != null) {
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(diretorioFotoImagem)};
            }
        } else {
            String dataString = data.getDataString();
            if (dataString != null) {
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
            }
        }
    }

    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
    mFilePathCallback = null;
    return;
}
```

Finalizando com o `onCreate()` que é o método responsável por carregar os `layouts` e outras operações de inicialização.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    // referencia o webview no layout/activity_main.xml
    meuWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    // define as configurações basicas
    setWebview(meuWebView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // retaura o webview
        meuWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    meuWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if(mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // cria local onde a foto deve ir
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = armazenarImagemTemp();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", diretorioFotoImagem);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    diretorioFotoImagem = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if(takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

            return true;
        }
    });

    // carrega a URL
    if(meuWebView.getUrl() == null) {
        meuWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.3:8080/api.finan.com/");
    }
}
```

**Obs.:** não esqueça de criar o `WebView` no seu XLM.

Para melhorar o código, confira mais detalhes [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

**EDIT**

Como você ressaltou nos comentário a questão da possibilidade para funcionar no *fragment*, faça o [download aqui da adaptação](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxfzFAS7MTC0elpiZHhncVNIVzg/view?usp=sharing) básica para funcionar.

Comment: so uma coisa se possível pode m orientar como adaptar este seu cod para funcionar dentro de um fragment? ou se você puder me manda um ex por favor?

Comment: @JasarOrion basicamente você tem que verificar duas coisas, que seria a questão da view, pois no lugar de this, é colocado getActivity() e a questão do onActivityResult() para seu fragment que é diferente um pouco. Tente fazer as modificações, caso não consiga, posso verificar depois pra ti. Você conseguiu testar?!

Comment: ok hoje anoite vou mecher nisso e volto a informar .muito obrigado

Comment: @JasarOrion fiz aqui pra você, vou disponibilizar em um link pode ser?! Senão a resposta fica muito grande!

Comment: poxa obrigado ^^ agradeço muito . sou iniciante no android este é o meu primeiro aplicativo da uma olhada no desapegogames.com.br

Comment: ja estou testando. tenho uma ultima dúvida. em caso de offline ou erro onde eu insiro a opção para carregar um arquivo html que esta la no asstes?

Comment: @JasarOrion meu caro, talvez seria melhor você adicionar uma outra pergunta, porque neste caso já sai fora do contexto.

Comment: cara deu certo aqui MUITO obrigado te adicionei no skype se você tiver tempo gostaria de saber quanto é sua hora para consultoria.

Comment: consegui implementar o erro tbm abraços. assim que liberar ja te premio pela ajuda muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: @JasarOrion muito bem cara. Nas minhas horas vagas tento ajudar as pessoas, retribuindo pelas muitas dúvidas que já tive e me ajudaram.